# Impact on Performance due to LockSupport.park while using Hazelcast IMap.lock()

Tags: multithreading, performance, hazelcast

We are using Hazelcast distributed object i.e. IMap for locking mechanism via IMap.trylock() API. we have to obtain and release a lock for each rest call. we observed a significant impact on our rest calls. On thread dump analysis we see that most of time is being spent on LockSupport.park() as mentioned in below different threads

```
"qtp1073885358-4211" - Thread t@4211

   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING

at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)

at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:304)

at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:161)

at com.hazelcast.concurrent.lock.LockProxySupport.tryLock(LockProxySupport.java:138)

at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.tryLock(MapProxyImpl.java:483)


   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING

at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)

at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:304)

at com.hazelcast.internal.util.concurrent.MPSCQueue.takeAll(MPSCQueue.java:231)

at com.hazelcast.internal.util.concurrent.MPSCQueue.take(MPSCQueue.java:153)

at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InboundResponseHandlerSupplier$ResponseThread.doRun(InboundResponseHandlerSupplier.java:283)

at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InboundResponseHandlerSupplier$ResponseThread.run(InboundResponseHandlerSupplier.java:272)


   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING

at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)

at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:304)

at com.hazelcast.internal.util.concurrent.MPSCQueue.takeAll(MPSCQueue.java:231)

at com.hazelcast.internal.util.concurrent.MPSCQueue.take(MPSCQueue.java:153)

at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationQueueImpl.take(OperationQueueImpl.java:85)

at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:105)
```

These calls are consuming a lot of time. Anybody has faced similar issue? and what can be probable fix?

Comment: Can you provide more information:  the lock obtaining and releasing code along with Hazelcast version? Also, is the thread contention for the same key or different keys? How many keys in the map? How many servers?